# Can't launch .exe from Java

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I am trying to launch a .exe file through a Java program. I used the following code:

```
System.out.println("Opening " + path);
Process exec;
exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + path);//path is the path of the exe file which is passed as an argument from another java class
```

the output is as follows:

```
Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\C-Free 5\CppIDE.exe
```

But it is not opening.

Instead when I try

```
String pat="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\C-Free 5\\CppIDE.exe";
Process exec;
exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + pat);
```

the program is opened.

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: What is the value of `path`?

Comment: You may need to wrap the "pat" in quotes "\"c:/Program Files/...\""

Comment: Sidenote: why do you use `rundll32` at all? The command you are calling is an `.exe` file, that you should be able to execute directly.

Comment: Also visit the JavaWorld article linked from the [exec tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) & implement all the recommendations.  I would be more surprised if that code worked, than if it failed.

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that the space in your path is the problem.

I suggest you pass the arguments as an array instead of passing a single string containing the whole command (alternatively you could quote the spaces correctly, but that's not quite as easy).

*Either*

- use [the `String[]` version of `Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) *or*
- switch to using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which has an altogether simpler and more intuitive API.

With `ProcessBuilder` this could look like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("rundll32", "SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL", path);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Also, I see no reason to invoke `rundll32` at all in this scenario. This should work just as well:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(path);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: The program uses Sockets.  The file path in a MySQL database at the Server side. It is read and send to the client via a ServerSocket.

I tried printing both 'path'(file path received from Server) and 'pat'(file path given in the program) and both are same. However when i use

   

 `Process exec;`


   
 `exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + path);`



The program (CppIDE) is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the path using [File.separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar). The path separator you are using will, in this case, will be system dependant.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, since `rundll32` is already *pretty* system dependent and every system that has that executable will use \ as the file separator.